# Is " Hammer it home" an idiom?

Tags: american-english

What does " Hammer it home" mean? I want to know if it refers to a sport event or not.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hammer+home

Comment: As terdon's link indicates, the idea is that the hammered-in nail's resting place is thenceforth its home.

Comment: You can just as easily [**drive** the point home](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22drive+the+point+home%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but I see no reason to suppose either usages derive from a sporting context (hammer-throwing, golf-driving, or whatever).

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Hammering* has more force than *driving* -- you can't politely hammer home a point. :)

Comment: @Kris - Sure you can, but it takes a lot of skill and diplomacy. Think about an auto body worker hammering out the dents in a car. Not every hammer is a sledgehammer.

Comment: @Kris: You can drive home a nail or a screw. A decent screwdriver probably generates more force than a hammer anyway, on account of the lever action of the screw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, it means "make the point abundantly, unforgettably clear." For example, "sending Johnny to his room should hammer home the idea that he should not pull his sister's hair."

According to the reference, yes, it is an idiom (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idiom and http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hammer+home). No, in my experience it does not refer to a sporting event.

Comment: The question is general reference and as such off-topic. And the answer is more in the nature of an opinion ('My understanding'; 'I would say'; 'I do not believe'; 'I suspect'). After all, it *is* an idiom.